# When to use super class method in subclass without override? is it possible?

Tags: android

I'm new to android. According to the code below, if  onListItemClick is a super class method, then why override is not used? and if it's a subclass method, then why when i change the method name, app crashes?!

```
class BasicViews5Activity extends ListActivity{

    //onCreate method here

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
   //some code here
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) contains a method

```
 protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

Therefore, your own implementation of that method in a class inheriting from `ListActivity` overrides the super class method.

In JAVA (and Android), the `@Override` annotation is optional. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) to find out more about the annotation and when to use it (short answer: always use `@Override`).